# Webextension: Access json dictionary from external url, How?

Tags: content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions, add-on

It is possible (though risky) to allow a webextension  in the browser to load javascript from a remote url using the following directive in the `manifest.json` file - by including something like:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'"
```

as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy#Example).

My question is how do I then go ahead and insert the javascript source file remotely housed on `https://example.com` ?

I tried in Firefox by adding at the top of my extension code:

```
var script_insert='<script src="https://example.com/dict.js"></script>';
document.write( script_insert + '\n' );
```

where `dict.js`contains:

```
window.dict_L1C = {
"a" : "hello",
"b" : "world"
}
```

but that fails with warnings:

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
```

I guess I'm doing it the wrong way, or I am missing something important.

**UPDATE:**
I am now looking at the solutions provides [here](https://bitkeks.eu/blog/2018/01/firefox-webextensions-injecting-sending-data-and-detecting-ajax.html#fetching-remote-content-and-posting)

Comment: You should be aware before continuing on this path, that extensions loading remote code can't be distributed via addons.mozilla.org https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/AMO/Policy/Reviews

Comment: The "warnings" aren't errors at all. They're simply informational notices that certain deprecated policies are being ignored because the newer policies that replace them are in effect.  So:  Policy A is deprecated, and replaced by Policy B.  You might still use A to cover older browsers that don't understand B; but new browsers that understand B will give you the notices you got -- that they're ignoring A and using B instead.

Comment: Correction/clarification: in your specific case, the one isn't deprecated at all; it's simply that when `strict-dynamic` is used, it supersedes both `unsafe-inline` and `https:`.  But still not an error.  Those notices are probably unrelated to why your code isn't working.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen-R - but how do I prevent my usage of `strict-dynamic` ?

Comment: @evilpie Yes - but I want to update my dictionary without users always having to update their add-on - so I am prepared to distribute my add-on away from the AMO. Unless there is a better way - perhaps using json?

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff Why would you? It’s not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how from within a webextension I managed to read a dictionary  from`https://www.remote-dictionary.com/dict.json`.
First create the `manifest.js` that contains a `permissions` section  as follows:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "mywebextension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "reads a dictionary from a remote website and uses it on another",

 "background": { "scripts": [ "background.js" ] },

  "content_scripts": [ { "matches": ["*://my-insertion-site.com/*"], "js": [  "content.js" ] } ],

  "permissions": [ "storage",  "https://www.remote-dictionary.com/*" ]
}
```

Next create the `background.js` file that accesses the remote dictionary and then stores it locally in the browser.

```js
if (typeof chrome !== 'undefined') { browser = chrome}

function fetchDict() {
    let req = new Request( "https://www.remote-dictionary.com/dict.json", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
        redirect: 'follow',
        referrer: 'client'
    });

    fetch(req).then(function(response) {
        // .json returns another promise
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        browser.storage.local.set({data: data}); // set storage for content-script
  }).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
}

fetchDict();
```

And the `content.js` script:

```js
if (typeof chrome !== 'undefined') { browser = chrome }

browser.storage.local.get({data: ""},function(data){ // get from local storage 
window.dict=data.data; 
  )
})

// later access the dictionary values:
window.dict[ "my_key"];
```